# Generating an Excel file on the fly in a Web site

Tags: php, asp.net, export-to-excel

Are there any good PHP libraries for exporting data to Excel files (not CSV files)?

(An alternative would be creating an ASP.NET Web service that handles Excel file generation, but I would rather not send complex objects over a network in XML format, unless it were strictly necessary.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+write+excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For PHP try [PHPEXCEL](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Excel will accept a standard HTML table masquerading as a .xls file:

```
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Just set the file extension and mime type on download to the client.

Comment: Clever technique. If you're doing something on the fly, that could come in handy.

Comment: That's not a good hack. It works only due to deficiencies in Windows. A filtering proxy or stricter security settings in Excel, while uncommon, are likely to break this.

Comment: It is used more often than not. Some versions of Excel will present a warning message that can be disabled, but I doubt a filtering proxy is going to block html.

Answer (score 2):

While not a "direct export" library, the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library looks to be a nice library for generating Excel files using PHP.

If you do go the .Net route, I highly recommend the [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) library.